# g++ creating static library: could not read the symbols archive has no index

Tags: c++, g++, sdl, static-libraries, unix-ar

I am trying to group a number of SDL utility classes into a static library for C++ using g++. I am using ubuntu linux 11.10 and gcc versión 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3). The version of ar is 2.21.53.20110810.

Since all files are small I am currently using only header files. I am mentioning this in case it has something to do with the problem. Also, most headers are compiled to object code with -lSDL (I am not sure that is right or even relevant, but it fails either way). Finally, there are a couple of static members for two different classes, defined in their own file to be included in the last steps of the process (triyng to follow the ODR).

Thing is, every file is compiled to object code just fine, then an archive is created using ar but when I try to compile the main file and link it against my new library like this (being libDanGfx.a the archive I am creating):

g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic newmain.cpp -L. -lSDL -lDanGfx

I get this error:

./libDanGfx.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

This happens even after deleting all archives and object code.

I have scouted the site and havent found an answer to the problem yet. Using ranlib did not help at all, also tried feeding the -m32 to my compiler but still to no avail. I tried in three different machines, all of them failed.

Franky, I am thinking of dropping this whole archive thing, update the makefile and just link with the object files but I really want to know what is happening here and learn a bit in the process.

I expect a lot of information to be missing so, just in case, I uploaded a .tar.gz file with the whole thing (just unpack and try the makefile). For your perusing, all .o files will be in the objects directory and every command used can be read in the makefile. Also, the main should display some mindless stuff on the screen (probably red squares since the resource files are not uploaded to save space, of course, .o and .a files are excluded as well).

The file can be reached [in this link](http://www.caballorenoir.net/hosted/motor_grafico.tar.gz).

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message said you should do? I.e. run the command [`ranlib`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ranlib)?

Comment: Joachim:

Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned "Using ranlib did not help at all". Tried some other things I saw in other questions (mostly running "file" on the object files to see if they spit out being precompiled headers) but got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question again and checking the archive, you only have the code in header files? But then you can't create a library! Header files are for including in source files, and not to be compiled into object files!

Split the headers up into proper header files with only declarations, and put definitions (i.e. the implementation) in source files. Compile the source files into object files that are used to create the library.

If there is no "implementation" and all code is inline in the header files, you don't need to make a library, just include the wanted header file.

Comment: Hi Joachim: Again, thanks a lot for a very quick answer!!!. That must be it, sure... I thought there was something strange on it but didn't give it much thought. I will try it ASAP but first, there are some templates there that I won't be able to generate .o files with .cpp, right?. What should I do with those?.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan Templates has to be all in header files, although non-templated helper functions may still be in source files. If the code is small enough that it can be easily inlined, then it's okay to have a header-only library (i.e. no library to link with, just header files to include).

Comment: Joachim: That just worked with little hassle (I just added includes to the header file in each cpp... I will put the implementation there later on). The compiler didn't complain at all on this computer. I will try later at home. Thanks a lot for your time, tips about header files and, of course, help!. The inlined code bit really helped make up my mind about that since I tend to write small classes.  (Edit: can't vote up due to low reputation, sorry).